# What kind of jumper wires are used with a breadboard?

Tags: jumper

What kind of jumper wires should I get for electronics and a breadboard?  There are female to female, male to female, female to female with headers.  I don't know what to get.  Just hookup wire?

Comment: I use #22 or 24 solid hookup wire (but the fancy jumper things weren't invented when I first used a plastic breadboard).

Comment: @PeterBennett What do you do when you need a female connection?

Comment: If I needed a female connector, I'd probably just take a couple of turns arond the pim with my solid wire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience, you should get all three types. Most of the time you will be using male-to-male and male-to-female.

Since using wires for breadboard connections can create quite a mess on the breadboard, I would also suggest getting these:

[image: Jumper wire]

Comment: Do you plug header pins right into the breadboard?

Comment: Yes, I usually plug header pins directly into the breadboard, whenever it is possible. You cannot plug 2-row headers directly (happens quite a lot), and that is when you can use male-to-female wires.

Comment: what is the name of the wires in the image?

Answer (score 3):

The standard solid strand breadboards wires are nice when making a nice clean circuit however they break quickly: 
http://tinyurl.com/z482nme

These are really nice in that they are made out of stranded wire with molded ends. They rarely break and are really easy to work with however they make a circuit messy fast: http://tinyurl.com/ha94t8e

Female/Female aren't very common. You mostly needs these for connecting male header pins on breakout boards not necesarrily bread boards but they are still nice to have around:
http://tinyurl.com/jhwwkpa

My advice is to buy all 3 of the above. It may look like a lot but it doesn't take long for them to get lost, melted, broken, etc.